# How to pick only 1 friend from Facebook API - FriendPickerSample?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, ios-simulator

Thanks in advance for helping me

I'm new to iOS development and developing a game with some connection to Facebook.
I downloaded Facebook SDK from Facebook and execute FriendPickerSampedle with XCode, I can get the name of my selected friends, but the problem is, how to pick only one friend from the list?

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBFriendPickerViewController/

FBFriendPickerViewController has a property:
allowsMultipleSelection
A Boolean value that specifies whether multi-select is enabled.

@property (nonatomic) BOOL allowsMultipleSelection;

```
FBFriendPickerViewController *fbfriendsVC = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
fbfriendsVC.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
```